# use javascript to get only the visible content in a span

Tags: javascript, html

I have a specific requirement to get the **exact content of first three lines displayed** in a span tag. If content in span exceeds three lines, only first three lines should be displayed, the rest of the content text should be clipped.
Using javascript I have completed till clipping of text after 3 lines. Now I need to get the text displayed in the first 3 lines of the span tag. Any help ?

```
<html>  
<body>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
function getHeight(){  
 document.getElementById('many').style.height = document.getElementById('simple').scrollHeight*3;  
document.getElementById('many').style.overflow = 'hidden';  
}  
</script>  
<span style='display:block' id='simple'>Single Line</span>  
<span style='display:block' id='many'>
Mutli Line Multi Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line
Mutli Line Multi Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line
Mutli Line Multi Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line
Mutli Line Multi Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line
Mutli Line Multi Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line
Mutli Line Multi Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line
Mutli Line Multi Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line Mutli Line
</span> 
 <br>
 <input type='button' onclick='getHeight()' value='click this to trim multi line'/>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: when you specify first three lines do you have a char limit? Because first three lines can be pretty broad.

Comment: I don't think you can clip a part of the content of a span, except by deleting it as it's an inline element

Comment: Fixing the number of lines is necessary coz depending upon the span's width number of chars that forces a wrap in the span varies. so setting char limit would be futile if the span's width varies.

Comment: When you say "get" only the visible content in the span, do you mean "cause only three lines to be displayed" or do you mean "extract into a JavaScript variable what words are displayed on the first three lines"? If the latter, I suggest that you (procedurally) wrap all words in spans and then use bounding-box intersections to determine if they are within the "first three lines" of height.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using jQuery for this. If the content doesn't actually need to be removed from the page, you can hide it using overflow: hidden;. The jQuery to do this would be quite simple too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    // Get the line height and multiply it by 3
    var three_lines = $('#many').css('line-height').replace(/[^0-9.]+/, '')*3;
    // Resize the span
    $('#many').css( {'display': 'block', 'height': three_lines, 'overflow': 'hidden'} );
});
</script>
```

Comment: The line-height css property will work only if it is defined.